# randomForest::varImp VS conditional variable importance

Tags: r, predictive-modeling, feature-selection, random-forest

**Data:**

My training set consists of ~450k obs and 26 variables, out of which 1 is an ordinal factor (order_month, 12 levels) and the rest is numerical. Moreover, some of my predictors are highly correlated (Pearson's > 0.5), which is expected and sometimes intentional.

I trained a good RF model (ROC 0.96, ~90% specificity & ~90% sensitivity when tested on unseen data) and I derived Variable importance for it using `varImp()`.

**Problem:**

Now, I know that having factorial and / or correlated predictors could result in biased variable selection in RF models, to which conditional inference trees (CIT) should be a remedy.

I tried to compare results of `randomForest::varImp()` with `party::varimp(myforest, conditional=TRUE)` however I get an error in the latter:

`Error in model.matrix.default(as.formula(f), data = blocks) : 
  term 1 would require 9e+12 columns`,

suggesting that I have either too many variables or variables with too many levels.

On top of that it takes over 24hrs to run `party::cforest()` and running `predict()` on CIT model crashes my computer altogether. Given the above, I have a couple of

**Questions:**

1) how likely is it that I may completely misclassify the top VarImps in RF model. Is running CIT here absolutely necessary?

2) what are alternative ways of obtaining conditional variable importance if not through `party::varimp()`?

Big thanks for your suggestions! Kasia

Comment: In response to question 2, maybe the [VSURF package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VSURF/index.html) could be useful for you. It seems to use `doParallel()` package which could improve the performance of the variable selection procedure.

Comment: very interesting, @Stereo, thanks for that! Will def give it a go!

Comment: absolutely! sorry for not doing it earlier! :)